# Solution for Hybrid architecture(MSsql and .NET)

Tags: .net, sql-server, amazon-web-services, azure, architecture

**Problem statement**

My organization is having an on-premises server for MSSQL 2016 and .NET application both on the same server, we are looking to create a DR(AWS or Azure) and it can bear 15-20 minutes of data loss.

**What is expected from Database:**

- Replication for MSsql with cloud database in case of
  primary(on-premises) server goes down we should be able to switch
  users to a cloud server(this includes both application and database)
- This might require continues sync or timely sync, interval sync is still ok considering 15 minutes loss of data.
- Once the users are switched to DR, it's data has to be synced back to the primary server once it gets up and we should be able to take back our users to on-premises(can be manual or automate both methods are ok with us).

**What is expected from .NET application server:**

- One of the directories has to be in two way sync with cloud .NET server(this typically includes files created or uploaded through an application)

Guys, I know it's a very small solution and I'm sending it here is primarily I've convinced an organization to use DR, and now they have given me an opportunity to design this and provide a proposal in minimal time, I've handled a few solutions over Linux and Mysql replications but I am totally new to Microsoft, so kindly help me to finish it.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest this approach to achieve this scenario.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a5g5mj2bekex6lf/20190131_135152.jpg?dl=0

1. Keep application code (.NET) on Azure Repo or any other source control and create CI/CD pipe line to deploy the application on On-prem - VM and Azure web app or VM on Azure. (But I recommend PaaS based Azure app service - web app). So when ever you do code changes, both the environment will get update. You can do testing for once in 6 month or some interval of period based on your organization BCP.

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-aspnet-core
2. Next, for SQL sysn you can use "Azure Data Sync" feature. Again I recommend Azure SQL - PaaS service. 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync
   Initial data migration can be done like this (Exercise -  01) : https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/aspnetmodernize/
3. So if there any fail, you can manually point the DNS to new Azure App service env.

Note : This approach is basically Active/passive method. You need some downtime for manual fail over. I have assumed you are using latest .NET version and it can be deployed to PaaS without code changes.

If you need further support, Please raise your question. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for the help though doesn't **"Azure data sync"** comes with limitations: 1) Each table must have the primary key. 2) A table cannot have an identity column that is not the primary key. 3) The names of the object cannot contain printable characters(period, left square bracket or right square bracket).

Comment: True. Then we have to go with traditional method, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transactional-replication-to-azure-sql-db/ or write a program and scheduled it on Azure Function.